# Dropdown menu problem IE7 - hidden

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

the problem is that in IE7, the dropdown under "**Departamentos**" its cut by the banner, and it seems to be pushed to the right...

This should be a very **easy** to fix but I have little experience with IE fixes... I try for some time but I need your help, can you check it out??

[Link to the Website](http://arojas.dinterweb.com/colono/)

Thanks

Comment: I can't tell what your problem is because there is too much code.  Do this -- save the file as HTML by doing "View Source" and save it in the root of your site.  Start taking out all the code, little by little, until you have just the minimum where the problem still happens.  Then, debug from there.

Comment: in Ie 8.0.6 and in FF 3.6.10 it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's same in IE8 because your document is rendered in quirks mode. Move the comments before the doctype declaration after the declaration. Anything before the doctype will trigger quirks mode in IE.

After you do that give .nav-wrap a z-index higher than #mainData and the submenu will show in IE7. Then give your submenu ul a left:0; to position it right.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I did what you said but still in IE7 is cutting behind the banner, I don't understand why, if it has z-index higher in the header...

Comment: You removed the stuff before the doctype, but the class .nav-wrap does still not have a z-index higher than #mainData.

Comment: I miss to add position to the header... Fixed, Thank you Daniel